# Json Returns extra values from entity

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using json .net to serlize an generic list but its bringing back extra data in my json respose when i only want my field names and values. I have tried using the JSONConvert simple syntax below but im thinking I going to have to create a new results var based on the value returned from myList.

```
public string GetListByUserId(int userId)
{

        List<curoList> myList = _db.GetAllListsByUserId(userId);

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);

        return json;

}
```

In the data its including things like EntitySetName when i just want the fields to be like fieldname:fieldvalue, and that leads me to my second question with json.net how would one turn the data into a List object

**Edit**

I forgot to include the test data for u guys.

> [{"$id":"1","id":1,"firstName":"David","lastName":"Buckley","address1":"","address2":null,"county":null,"postcode":null,"emailaddress":null,"aboutme":null,"active":true,"EntityKey":{"$id":"2","EntitySetName":"persons","EntityContainerName":"curoEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"id","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"1"}]}}]

**Eidt 2** 
This is to show how I am creating my data

```
public List<person> GetPersonByIdDal(int personId)
{
        List<person> list = new List<person>();

        try
        {
            list = (from myPersons in curoEntities.persons where myPersons.id == personId && myPersons.active==true select myPersons).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new EntityContextException("GetPersonById where active = true failed.", ex);
        }

        return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the vote up whoever it was ;-)

Comment: we use list with complex object with json net and it does not give us any extra data. i am guessing you are seeing this is because of the way you db container is returning the object. What is the entity type sent out by your db container.

Comment: You can mark properties you don't want with [`[JsonIgnore]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm).  Of if you want to ignore all base class properties, say, you could do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063259/jproperty-writeto-with-collections-in-a-jsonconverter.  But to give a real answer it would help to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: @dbc i have shown my problem above and test data their in edit 1 and edit 2

Comment: I would change the select to return an anonymous type and only declare the fields that you want. `.select(x => new { ID=  x.id ... })`

Answer (score 0):

The entity-keys probably comes from your ORM. Are you using Entity-Framework? You can either use Ignore, or you can do something like

```
var myList = _db.GetAllListsByUserId(userId).Select(x=> new SomeDto{ prop1 = x.prop1 ... }).toList(); 

public class SomeDto{
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
}
```

This will give you a List object that contains only what you define, it also makes the query faster as long as you dont want the entire resultset to be in there.

If youre using Entity framework, your db-context can also be configured  in the dbcontext settings, where its possible to turn of stuff like proxy-creation. Be carefull doing that on a global scale, since it might mess up your update-tracking.

Comment: I am just using my own class in entity but cuase i using a List its bringing back the etc properties, as about I will try what you suggested in the monring but where does proper1 come from ? as see its classed as a var their and not of type object list?

Comment: var was just used to make it simpler. The proper return value for this would be List<SomeDto>, which i added as a data-transfer-object class underneath for the occasion. The entity-things is attached because the object is still a proxy and attached to the context.

Comment: So i guess your using an ORM, which looks like Entity Framework or something similar. 

Your Person-object is probably bound as an entity against your context from what i can see in your query. All the extra properties will be in there because the object that you fetch from the context/database is still attached to the context. Selecting it to a new object will solve your problem, though not the cleanest solution. Disabling your contexts proxy-creation should help. For performance, my solution will not help at all, since you have allready fetched all the records from the database at that point