# Entity Framework Subclass Not Mapped

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, json.net

I am trying to create a method off of my DbContext that will allow me to retrieve a collection of entities as a subclass of the base entity.  And, I don't want the subclass to be mapped and/or stored in the database.

I am trying to do this to create an entity that has our entity as the superclass that can be serialized/de-serialized against a 3rd party REST API.

For example:

My Entity

```
// our legacy entity - EF code first
// stored in our database
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Title {get;set;}
}

// example 3rd party "wrapper" for JSON serialization
public class ShopifyProduct : Product
{
    [NotMapped]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.Title; }
        set { this.Title = value; }
    }
}
```

So I would like to be able to retrieve the Product objects as ShopifyProduct instead of Product.

So something like this

```
using (var context = new ProcessorDbContext())
{
    foreach (var product in context.Product<ProductShopify>())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I want to avoid is putting the JsonPropertyAttribute on our original entities because then the entities would be locked to one specific API.  I could see having a ShopifyProduct, an EbayProduct, etc and the JsonPropertyAttribute would start to clash.

Any anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: Oh, and if it wasn't clear, I don't want to have to modify the underlying DB.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what exactly you want to do.  If you're looking only to serialize the properties of the derived class and omit the base properties, see [JProperty.WriteTo with collections in a JsonConverter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063259/jproperty-writeto-with-collections-in-a-jsonconverter).

Comment: It's not really clear but it seems that you need (you have) a View Model different from the Persistency Layer Entities. In my experience, I can't solve all the possible issues inheriting from Persistency Layer Entities so usually the View Model entities are not inherited from the Persistency Layer Entities and I copy values with a mapper (i.e. Automapper).