# Serialize only derived type using Newtonsoft Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there any JsonSerializerSettings available for serializing only the derived type.

for example consider i have below two class. When I am serializing Employee object the the result json should only contains the properties of employee not the person class.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Do you always want `Name` to be ignored anytime you're serializing a child type of `Person`? If so, just a simple ignore attribute should do the trick.

Comment: This is a just a example I gave. But my real base class is having multiple properties and in-depth object graph. So just don't want to serialize the any of base class properties.

Comment: Tag the properties in the base class with the JsonIgnore attribute, as mason suggested. That should do the trick.

Comment: If there are still situations where you might want a serialized Person (or any child type) to have the base class properties, then an ignore attribute won't work. I would think you would be be better served by creating a Data Transfer Object and then serializing that. Perhaps using something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to go from your Employee object to your DTO.

Comment: @ Dag - My Base class is having more properties with in-depth object graph. So trying to avoid adding jsonignore to all properties. Also I may want base class properties also need to be serialized in some scenario later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JProperty.WriteTo with collections in a JsonConverter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063259/jproperty-writeto-with-collections-in-a-jsonconverter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions like those usually reflect an issue with model design, however, one way to do what you want to do is to get rid of the inheritance; you could try something like converting your object to dynamic and then serialize the dynamic object :

```
class MyJson
{
    public static string SerializeObject<T>(T obj, bool ignoreBase)
    {
        if (!ignoreBase)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        }

        var myType = typeof(T);
        var props = myType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.DeclaringType == myType).ToList();

        var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        props.ForEach(p => x.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(obj, null)));

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
    }
}
```

call it like

```
MyJson.SerializeObject<Employee>(e, true)
```

This way you can use it for any type and filter the properties to serialize however you wish in the helper class. For example, you can check the property attributes and decided if it should be added to the dynamic object.

Comment: no sometimes it's just related to how objcts are stored in memory, if for exemple you have an ObjectA : BaseA
if you send ObjectA in a method that  takes BaseA as a parameter, for ex : 
DoSomething(BaseA parameter)  when you serialize the parameter you will have all objectA properties serialised, this is tricky since sometimes you do'nt want that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `JsonConverter` for that purpose. Please see below for a basic version for your purpose.

```
public class PersonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(Employee))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return "";
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

        if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
        {
            t.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            JObject o = (JObject)t;

            o.Remove("Name"); //currently the property name is hardcoded. You could enhance this to remove any property you like

            o.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

After creating your `JsonConverter` you can use that during deserialization like below,

```
var des = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e, new PersonConverter());
//e is the Person instance we want to convert and PersonConverter is the custom converter
//we use of serialization
```

Please see this [link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for more information on this

Comment: Thanks. It is good solution. But still thinking anything simpler than this.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing you have to tweak in above code is the way want to find the property names that need to be removed. Depending on your requirements you have to decide on the best approach to configure the property names.