# How to Omit Inherited Property From JSON.NET Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, schema.org

If I have the following classes I want to serialize using JSON.NET:

```
[DataContract]
public class Thing
{
    [DataMember(Name = "@context")]
    public string Context => "http://schema.org"
}

[DataContract]
public class Organization : Thing
{
    [DataMember(Name = "address")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    ...
}

[DataContract]
public class Address : Thing
{
    ...
}
```

When I use JSON.NET to serialize an Organization I get:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "address": {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

What is the most efficient way of ensuring that the `@context` property only appears in the top level `Organization` object and not in the `Address` object?

Comment: You could use something like `EverythingButBaseContractResolver` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30065294/3744182).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Organization` is the only top level descendant of `Thing` and also no fields of type `Organization` may appear in serialized objects, you may easily do this by defining `ShouldSerializeContext` in `Thing` as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class Thing
{
    [DataMember(Name = "@context")]
    public string Context => "http://schema.org";
    public bool ShouldSerializeContext() { return this is Organization; }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GjmfbA

---

If any of the `Thing`'s descendants may act as the root object, you may need to implement a custom converter. In `WriteJson` method of this converter, you may filter properties to be serialized. To remove the `Context` property from all but the root object check `writer.Path`, which will be an empty string for the root object:

```
[DataContract]
[JsonConverter(typeof(NoContextConverter))]
public class Thing
{
    [DataMember(Name = "@context")]
    public string Context => "http://schema.org";
}

// ...............

public class NoContextConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var props = value.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(DataMemberAttribute)))
            .ToList();
        if (writer.Path != "")
            props.RemoveAll(p => p.Name == "Context");

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(prop.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>().Name);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, prop.GetValue(value, null));
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Thing).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cIlXID

*N.B. For some reason, dotnetfiddle.net does not allow to use `DataContractAttribute` and `DataMemberAttribute` from `System.Runtime.Serialization` so I had to comment out relevant lines in this demo.*

Comment: There are many top level descendants of `Thing`. In fact, `Address` is also one and I may want to serialize `Address` on it's own also. What can I do then?

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed, I'll be posting a suggestion for more complex cases in a few minutes...

Comment: I'm thinking it might be quicker to do a string replace on the JSON than use reflection.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed: well, perhaps. But looking for `"@context": "http://schema.org"` if the actual value varies may turn out a big challenge by itself. Taking into account possible quotes in quotes and lookup string being a part of some other attribute value you well may end up with using a full blown JSON parser (depending on the actual data, of course.) On the other hand, you may introduce a type cache in the custom `NoContextConverter` and then all reflection (apart from `prop.GetValue(value, null)`) would be done only once per type.

Comment: And even that `prop.GetValue(value, null)` may be converted to some non-reflection piece of code and cached, I believe. The latter would require some bigger effort but I guess this is what Json.Net employs internally.

Comment: I've marked your answer as the correct one. However, I've also added my own answer after playing around for a bit. It only works because I control the serialization and the context property.

Answer (score 0):

While @DimitryEgorov's answer is probably the correct way to go, it uses reflection which makes it slow. In the solution below, I use `StringBuilder` to do a string replace on the final JSON.

```
private const string ContextPropertyJson = "\"@context\":\"http://schema.org\",";

public override string ToString() => RemoveAllButFirstContext(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new JsonSerializerSettings));

private static string RemoveAllButFirstContext(string json)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(json);
    var startIndex = ContextPropertyJson.Length + 1;
    stringBuilder.Replace(
        ContextPropertyJson, 
        string.Empty, 
        startIndex, 
        stringBuilder.Length - startIndex - 1);
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```